# M2 - Translate password requirements alert

Tags: magento2, localisation, password, translate

In Magento 2 on the checkout page, you'll see a notification if you enter a password that not matches the requirements.

You see this: "Minimum of different classes of characters in password is 3. Classes of characters: Lower Case, Upper Case, Digits, Special Characters."

How can I translate that message? I've already tried to add the string in the csv translate file, but with no result...

Update:
[image]

Comment: What you have written in csv to translate this message? Can you post the csv line which you have written?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to translate the phrase

"Minimum of different classes of characters in password is 3. Classes of characters: Lower Case, Upper Case, Digits, Special Characters."

which is wrong. The correct line to be translated is the following:

" Minimum of different classes of characters in password is %1. Classes of characters: Lower Case, Upper Case, Digits, Special Characters. "

Where the %1 will automatically display the number of different character classes required by your store depending on the value you`ve set in your backend.

Comment: I think that should be it indeed... I will try in a moment.

Comment: I've added the screen what I've done in the CSV but it's not working...